# Why does the Azure Computer Vision service gives less confidence score for the captions generated for an Image?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

This is the code I am using:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(
                            computer_vision_endpoint, 
                            CognitiveServicesCredentials(computer_vision_key)
                        )

image_url = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/20/07/10/architecture-5195171_960_720.jpg"

description_results = computervision_client.describe_image(image_url )

if len(description_results.captions) == 0:
    print("Computer Vision cannot detect the caption for this image.")
else:
    print("The tags identified are: ", description_results.tags)
    for caption in description_results.captions:
        print("The caption is: ", caption.text)
        print("The confidence score is: {:.2f}%".format(caption.confidence * 100))
```

It gives a confidence score of 37%. Although the image description generated is nice. This happens with other images too.

Answer (score 0):

The system return low score when there was no certain elements in the image, like if the image is black and white, the description with black and white will be a high score. The quality of the image also effects the score. But for the image you mentioned I agree with you that the score is low for about 0.376 for the description of "a lighthouse on a rocky cliff"

I have forwarded this image to product group for more investigation. Thanks for the feedback again.